# checking the mysql table with node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database, discord.js

I create a discord bot and I need help with the code snippet, I need to check if in the mysql database in the table "player" is nickname identical to the nickname of the person who used the command.  Here's my code:

```
switch (message.content) {
    case (prefix+"vip"):
        con.query('SELECT * FROM gracz', (err, result, fields) => {
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log(result);
            console.log(result.gracze);
            if(message.author.username == result.gracze) {
                message.channel.sendMessage("jajko");
                console.log("jajko");
            } else {
                console.log("Niema jajka!");
                console.log(result.gracze);
            }
            console.log(result.gracze);
        });
        break;

}
```

It's working, when i type "result[and here id from database]" and i need to automate this, but i don't know how :(
"gracze" in this code id column in table "gracz" :)

my problem is that I have to type in between [] id manually to make it work, and I have to do it to detect it automatically.
If I have not expressed myself clearly, I will answer the questions in the commentary.
And I'm sorry for this English, I'm from Poland and I can not write English very well, so I used Google translator :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by your question

**If you want to use a variable in bracket notation:**
Just put the variable inside the brackets
Example: `a[id]`
Whatever `id` is it will index for it, if`id` is "saddy" then it would be the same as `a["saddy"]` or `a.saddy`

**If you mean you want a variable inside `con.query`:**

since you are using ` you can put variable values in {} and it will be the variables value

**If this isn't want you are asking please say and explain it a bit more. Hope this helps!**